# Errors with espeak

Tags: audio

I am getting an error using espeak. Audio comes out the head phone jack, but all of this stuff get written to the command line. I installed espeak and alsa-utils. Any idea how to fix these errors?

```
[kevin@raspberrypi ~]$ sudo espeak "hello"
[sudo] password for kevin: 
ALSA lib pcm.c:2217:(snd_pcm_open_noupdate) Unknown PCM cards.pcm.front
ALSA lib pcm.c:2217:(snd_pcm_open_noupdate) Unknown PCM cards.pcm.rear
ALSA lib pcm.c:2217:(snd_pcm_open_noupdate) Unknown PCM cards.pcm.center_lfe
ALSA lib pcm.c:2217:(snd_pcm_open_noupdate) Unknown PCM cards.pcm.side
ALSA lib pcm.c:2217:(snd_pcm_open_noupdate) Unknown PCM cards.pcm.surround40
ALSA lib pcm.c:2217:(snd_pcm_open_noupdate) Unknown PCM cards.pcm.surround41
ALSA lib pcm.c:2217:(snd_pcm_open_noupdate) Unknown PCM cards.pcm.surround50
ALSA lib pcm.c:2217:(snd_pcm_open_noupdate) Unknown PCM cards.pcm.surround51
ALSA lib pcm.c:2217:(snd_pcm_open_noupdate) Unknown PCM cards.pcm.surround71
ALSA lib pcm.c:2217:(snd_pcm_open_noupdate) Unknown PCM cards.pcm.iec958
ALSA lib pcm.c:2217:(snd_pcm_open_noupdate) Unknown PCM cards.pcm.iec958
ALSA lib pcm.c:2217:(snd_pcm_open_noupdate) Unknown PCM cards.pcm.iec958
ALSA lib pcm.c:2217:(snd_pcm_open_noupdate) Unknown PCM cards.pcm.hdmi
ALSA lib pcm.c:2217:(snd_pcm_open_noupdate) Unknown PCM cards.pcm.hdmi
ALSA lib pcm.c:2217:(snd_pcm_open_noupdate) Unknown PCM cards.pcm.modem
ALSA lib pcm.c:2217:(snd_pcm_open_noupdate) Unknown PCM cards.pcm.modem
ALSA lib pcm.c:2217:(snd_pcm_open_noupdate) Unknown PCM cards.pcm.phoneline
ALSA lib pcm.c:2217:(snd_pcm_open_noupdate) Unknown PCM cards.pcm.phoneline
ALSA lib pcm_dmix.c:957:(snd_pcm_dmix_open) The dmix plugin supports only playback stream
ALSA lib pcm_direct.c:877:(snd1_pcm_direct_initialize_slave) slave plugin does not support mmap interleaved or mmap noninterleaved access
ALSA lib pcm_dmix.c:1030:(snd_pcm_dmix_open) unable to initialize slave
Cannot connect to server socket err = No such file or directory
Cannot connect to server request channel
jack server is not running or cannot be started
```

Comment: What's the problem? You say it's working?

Comment: Yes, I get audio, however it typically is **not normal** to have all of these warnings and errors printed to the command line. I would like to fix this.

Comment: I am getting the same error messages but the audio is not normal. There is always a delay at the start of each sentence. Can anyone help, please?

Comment: What do you mean "not normal"?

Comment: related: http://unix.stackexchange.com/q/76025/82256

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**Here is the short solution:**

```
sudo espeak "hello" 2>/dev/null
```

**Here is my explanation:**

The output you're seeing is normal.

Jack is an audio server and the errors report that Jack is not installed. There's nothing wrong with this, `espeak` will just use a different audio engine such as `ALSA` or `Pulse`. In your case it looks like it's using `ALSA`.

The above command will just hide the output from you.

Comment: Doesn't that mean espeak is being a bit too verbose and printing it out to stderr poorly? If it's not really an error, anyway.

Comment: @Shurane Yes it is.

Comment: Is it possible to get audio output to HDMI and not to head phone jack?

Comment: @avra That should happen by default if your HDMI device supports it. If not then there should be something in the espeak documentation.

Comment: Yes it does work after all. My mistake.

Answer (score 3):

You can get rid of the annoying messages about jack by running the jack server with the following command line:

`jackd -r -m -p 8 -d dummy`

I put this in my `~/.config/autostart/jackd.desktop`

```
[Desktop Entry]

Type=Application

Name=jackd

Exec=jackd -p 8 -r -m -d dummy > /dev/null 2>&1

StartupNotify=false
```

Answer (score 2):

Found the answer for this here:

http://alexpb.com/notes/articles/2012/11/14/error-when-playing-audio-on-raspbian-on-a-raspberry-pi/

in

```
/usr/share/alsa/alsa.conf 

   change the line "pcm.front cards.pcm.front"
             to "pcm.front cards.pcm.default"
```

worked for me. Can't tell if there is other better solution.

Comment: The link is dead

Answer (score 0):

Turns out pulseaudio ruins ALSA.
For me, espeak worked with 'sudo' only.
After apt-get --purge remove pulseaudio, things got back to normal.